# How to clear contents of a column in excel sheet using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to clear contents of 3 columns in excel sheet(.xlsx file) using java before execution of my selenium script. i am using XSSFWorkbook(Apache poi) for read and write data to excel sheet.There are 5 columns in excel sheet.I want to clear 3 column contents and remaining column content should keep like before.

please help me how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream objFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    Xlsx_File_path.xlsx));
XSSFWorkbook objWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(objFileInputStream);
XSSFSheet objSheet = objWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
Cell cell = null;
int row=[start of row]
int cell=[your cell]


//iterate the below code as you want
//code
  cell = objSheet.getRow(rows).getCell(cell);
  cell.setCellValue("")
//code

objFileInputStream.close();
FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    finalXlsx.xlsx));
    objWorkbook.write(output_file);
            output_file.close();
```

Comment: Thanks @Kishan..I think it will take more time if i will clear 3 columns with hundreds of data.Because in my case 1column having 200+ data.Is there any in-built methos in poi to that?

Comment: The OOXML format stores contents in rows, so any operation on a column tends to be expensive because you have to iterate over all the rows. A built in method wouldn't be much more efficient. Also decide if you want to set the text to empty string or you want to delete the cell altogether.